# Represent dynamic tree with RDF

Tags: dynamic, graph, rdf, permutation

I'm trying to describe a sort of dynamically generated directed graph in RDF, where the value of each node depends on the 'summed state" of the nodes ahead of it.  For example the first node can have *n* values. Depending on which it is, there might be *m* child nodes, each with one of *k* values. Each of these might have *l* child nodes, and so on and so on.

So an RDF statement can easily any 2 nodes and an edge between them. As you go through the graph though, the subject or parent node effectively describes the values of all its ancestor nodes.

Is there a way to represent such a graph without having an entity for every valid permutation of node values to represent the subject of an RDF triple?

As an example, say I want to capture some relationships in a domain in an ontology with these properties:

```
can_input_to  rdfs:domain material       ; rdfs:range first_process .
can_feed_into rdfs:domain first_process  ; rdfs:range second_process .
has_output    rdfs:domain second_process ; rdfs:range widget .
```

And some statements about instances like this:

```
<material_a> <can_input_to> <first_process_a>
<material_b> <can_input_to> <first_process_a>
<material_c> <can_input_to> <first_process_b>
<material_d> <can_input_to> <first_process_b>

<first_process_a> <can_feed_into> <second_process_a>   //If input is <material_a> OR <material_b>
<first_process_b> <can_feed_into> <second_process_a> //If input is <material_d> 

<second_process_a> <has_output> <widget_a>    //If input is <material_a> AND first_process is <first_process_a>
<second_process_a> <has_output> <widget_b>    //If input is <material_a> AND first_process is <first_process_b>
```

How could the conditions on these statements (//If input is ..) be defined or captured in the ontology?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the type of graph you're trying to represent?  Are you just trying to encode a graph that you've already dynamically generated, or are you trying to specify a bit of the graph and then use inference to determine more of it?  Can you provide a specific example?  This might be achiveable, or it might not be, but it's hard to tell without seeing a more concrete example.  I know what permutations are, but I'm not clear how they're relevant here.

Comment: Hi Joshua, perhaps I was using 'permutations' a bit loosely. Question edited.

Comment: OK, I'm still not quite sure what you're asking, but I think it's getting clearer.  In the first code block, are `<material>` and `<first_process>` individuals?  Or are they classes, and you're saying that they are the domain and range of the `<can_input_to>` property?  If the latter is what you mean, then I think you'll be able to to do your "if/then" rules as SWRL rules (or, depending on how complex they are, maybe even OWL axioms).

Comment: Are you trying to say in the first case something like `Process(?p1) & Process(?p2) & Material(?m) & canInputTo(?m,?p1) -> canFeedInto(?p1,?p2)`?  That's something you can do with SWRL rules.  (I think there's still a condition missing there, because I don't quite understand your rules, but I think it's close enough for the moment.)

Comment: Yep, the first block is classes with domain and range. The rest is about individuals of those classes. What I'm trying to get at is how to express the dependency in the last statements on the value of the individual in the other statements.

Comment: I'm not clear what your dependencies are yet, though.  Rather than writing the specific instance, e.g., "If input is material_a OR material_b", can you write the general rule, just in English is fine, that you're trying to capture?  Something like, "A first process A can feed into a second Process B if ...".  I'm not clear what the general rule is yet from the code blocks above.  What's the  connection between `"<first_process_a> <can_feed_into> <second_process_a>"` and `If input is <material_a> OR <material_b>`.  I'm still missing something in the logic, I think.

Comment: In plainer(!) English:
second_process_a  will output a widget of type widget_a if the process feeding into it is of type first_process_a and the input to that process was of type material_ a

Comment: On the relationship between "<first_process_a> <can_feed_into> <second_process_a>"  and "If input is <material_a> OR <material_b>"
I'm after something that basically describes the same thing as these  statements would:
"<first_process_a_when_input_is_material_a> <can_feed_into> <second_process_a>"  
"<first_process_a_when_input_is_material_b> <can_feed_into> <second_process_a>"

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm missing something here:  are `<first_process_a>`, `<second_process_a>` (`<…_a>` and `<…_b>`, more generally) _individuals_, or _subclasses_ of `first_process`, etc.?

Comment: You've said that `<first_process_a> <can_feed_into> <second_process_a>` _if_ `input is <material_a> OR <material_b>`.  You've left implicit that you're talking about the input to `first_process_a` (since the domain of `has_input_to` is `first_process`), and that these are the acceptable inputs because `<material_a> <can_input_to> <first_process_a>` and `<material_b> <can_input_to> <first_process_a>`.  What I don't yet grasp is how `second_process_a` is special here. Why not `second_process_a2` or `second_process_a3` as well?  There's some connection between `first_process_a` and …

Comment: `second_process_a` that I'm missing.  It's not `can_feed_into`, because that's what you're trying to infer.  Is there some `might_be_able_to_feed_into` that's left implicit here?  E.g., that the `1stA` could feed into `2ndA` _if_ `1stA` gets an acceptable input?

Comment: Yes, this is correct: "Is there some might_be_able_to_feed_into that's left implicit here? E.g., that the 1stA could feed into 2ndA if 1stA gets an acceptable input? "

Comment: OK, well, where does it come from (or just, what is it)?  If you can make it explicit (e.g., add it to the instance data), then it's easy to write this logic in a SWRL rule.

Comment: <fisrt_process_a> etc. are individuals

Comment: I guess it's 'adding to the instance data' that I'm unsure of! I think I need to sit back and have a look at my problem again, and check out SWRL.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45728/discussion-between-user814425-and-joshua-taylor)

Answer (score -1):

This type of dynamic inference of child values based on parent nodes and inference rules is starting to be introduced into popular graphstores. For instance [Apache Jena supports inferrence rules written in RDFS, or OWL](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/). [Pellet](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/) is an OLW 2 reasoner for Java that you could use.